# Scrollviewer doesnt show data when its beyond parent window in wpf

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

There are some 6 contentcontrols within a single grid with 6 expanders(each contentcontrol in one expander)
on my mainwindow which calls various usercontrols to fill the mainwindow for each upper tab/left menu selection.

One expander would be active at a time and rest would be collapsed.

Each new window would be on a contentcontrol.

The problem was when i have larger data thats loading dynamically my content exceeds beyond the parent control and 
even when i use scrollviewer ,scrollviewer shows up but data is cut off.

Here is my code:
Following is my Code in UserControl that was used in contentcontrol of mainwindow

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Expander Header="Settings" BorderBrush="SteelBlue" BorderThickness="5"
      IsExpanded="{Binding Path=ShowPreview, Mode=TwoWay}"
      Background="AliceBlue" FontFamily="Poor Richard" FontSize="24"
      FontWeight="Bold">
    <DatePicker Name="MyDateRange" />
  </Expander>
  <Expander Header="Permissions" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="SteelBlue"
      BorderThickness="5" Background="AliceBlue" FontFamily="Poor Richard"
              <local:Permissions /> 
        <!--/*Permissions is another usercontrol   with a grid layout  (a dataentry form)*/-->
   </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Second grid with 6 rows was code in my MainWindow.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Expander Grid.Row="1" IsExpanded="False" x:Name="Expander1"
      Style="{DynamicResource OutlookStyleExpanderStyle}" Visibility="Hidden">
    <Expander.Header>
      <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="450,0,0,0">
        <Button Name="ExpandButtonMin" Background="#FFACD0EE"
            Click="ExpandButtonMin_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
          <Image Source="/Images/Minimize_Box_Blue.png" Height="30" Width="30" />
        </Button>
        <Button Name="ExpandButtonMax" Background="#FFACD0EE"
            Click="ExpandButtonMax_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
          <Image Source="/Images/maximize.png" Height="30" Width="30" />
        </Button>
        <Button Name="ExpandButtonClose" Background="#FFACD0EE"
            Click="ExpandButton1_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
          <Image Source="/Images/Close_Box_Red.png" Height="30" Width="30" />
        </Button>
      </WrapPanel>
    </Expander.Header>
   <ScrollViewer MaxHeight="800">
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="contentControl1"
        Content="{Binding ContentControlOne}" Margin="0,0,0,0"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
   </ScrollViewer>
  </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Similarly there are five expander rows with contentcontrol2,..in each of them.

The problem was when my contentcontrol has  max dynamic content that exceeds parent size ,data is cut off and scrollviewer shows up but still doesnt show complete data. When i remove the scrollviewer height and keep scrollviewer height to "Auto", scrollviewer doesnt show up at all.

Comment: can you share your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nicholas' answer is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28586372/302677) that your problem is how you're defining the RowDefinition of the Grid.

`Auto` means "allow children to grow to any size they want", so your ScrollViewer is growing to up to 800px high (because of the `MaxHeight`), which is off the screen.

The standard solution for this kind of thing is to use a Converter in the `RowHeight` to set it to either `Auto` or `"*"` ("allow child to take up all remaining space") based on the `Expander.IsExpanded` state.

This means if the Expander is collapsed, it will take up whatever space it needs, but if it's expanded it will take up all remaining space (and no more than that).

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=Expander1, Converter={x:Static MyBoolToGridSizeConverter}}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=Expander2, Converter={x:Static MyBoolToGridSizeConverter}}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=Expander3, Converter={x:Static MyBoolToGridSizeConverter}}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=Expander4, Converter={x:Static MyBoolToGridSizeConverter}}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=Expander5, Converter={x:Static MyBoolToGridSizeConverter}}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=Expander6, Converter={x:Static MyBoolToGridSizeConverter}}" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Expander Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Expander1">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl1" Content="{Binding ContentControlOne}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Expander>
     ...
</Grid>
```

If more than one item is expanded, they should split the remaining space evenly because they both share a size of `"1*"`, so would get allocated an equal amount of space.

Creating a converter is simple. Create a class that inherits from `IValueConverter`, implement the interface, and alter the `Convert` method to convert the bool value (`IsExpanded`) to a `GridLength` value for the RowHeight.

```
public class BoolToGridSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool && (bool)value)
            return new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);

        return GridLength.Auto;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // this is not needed
    }
}
```

Then add an instance of this converter to your XAML Resources somewhere, such as

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolToGridSizeConverter x:Key="MyBoolToGridSizeConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Of course, the other alternative is to google for a free WPF Accordion control, such as the one in the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535) :)

Comment: Thank u very much Rachel for your time.This helps.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that by setting all the heights of your `Grid`'s rows to "Auto", you end up with a `StackPanel`. And so no cell is forced to a smaller height than the height it needs, and so `ScrollViewer` is useless.

The height of the expanded expander row must be "*". Think of it as "Each expander takes the height it needs, except the active one who takes all the remaining".

Maybe something like that :

```
<Grid>
  <Expander x:Name="Expander1" ... />
  <Expander x:Name="Expander2" ... />
  <Expander x:Name="Expander3" ... />
  ...
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=Expander1, Converter={x:Static BoolToRowHeightConverter.Instance}}"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=Expander2, Converter={x:Static BoolToRowHeightConverter.Instance}}"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=Expander3, Converter={x:Static BoolToRowHeightConverter.Instance}}"/>
    ...
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

`BoolToRowHeightConverter` returns `GridLength.Star` if true, else `GridLength.Auto`.

Comment: Even after using converter and switching height to Auto and *,the data is still cutoff .Added scrollviewer vertical to Auto but still scrollviewer didnt appear and the data was cutoff.

Comment: Which height did you switch to auto after using converter ?

.. When you set height as Auto, it will take as much space as it wants, you have to decide where to draw boundary

Comment: Each Expander indeed has a 3 datagrids where data is dyncamically loading .so I cant set a fixed height .The only boundary was parent window.