# how to set heights of 3 DataGrids inside Extenders in one StackPanel in MVVM dynamically?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

The heights of each DataGrid should depend on:

1. Are other Extenders extended
2. How many rows the DataGrid has
3. If other Extenders are extended, how many rows other DataGrids have.
4. Height of the StackPanel the Extenders are in

All Extenders should be always visible.

If e.g. opening only upmost Extender and its DataGrid has 100 rows the Height of the DataGrid should be almost the height of StackPanel but in the bottom the two other Extenders should be visible and upmost DataGrid scrollable.

When opening 2 or 3 Extenders the StackPanel should be "full" if there is enough data in DataGrids.

[image]

I tried to bind the height properties (for undermost expander Objec information)

```
    <Expander Header="Object information" IsExpanded="{Binding ObjectInformationExpanded}">
        <DataGrid Name="ObjectInformationGrid" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedObjectAttributes}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  Height="{Binding ObjectInformationHeight, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Field" Binding="{Binding Item1}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Item2}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
</Expander>
```

But now my ViewModel has lots of code that is related to presentation (View) and still didn't take the StackPanel's height into the calculation. Instead I set the hardcoded double values which can't be good solution.

Here is bit of simple code that updates the bound height Properties (here for upmost DataGrid only) when extenders are opened/closed and DataGrid bound collections are changed:

```
   private void UpdateHeights()
   {
        if (SelectedObjectsExpanded == true)
        {
            if (_selectedObjects.Count == 0)
            {
                SelectedObjectsHeight = double.NaN;
            }
            else if (_selectedObjects.Count < 8)
            {
                SelectedObjectsHeight = 100;
            }
            else
            {
                if (ObjectInformationExpanded && SelectedSwitchesExpanded)
                    SelectedObjectsHeight = 100;
                else
                    SelectedObjectsHeight = 200;
            }
        }
        //...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28632233/302677) work?

The basic idea is put all 3 `Expanders` in a Grid containing 3 rows, and bind the `RowDefinition.Height` of each row to the `Expander.IsExpanded`. A Converter is used to set the value to `Auto` if the expander is collapsed (only take up the space needed), or `*` if it's expanded (take up all remaining space. If multiple rows are set to `*` height, share space evenly between them).

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=Expander1, Converter={x:Static MyBoolToGridSizeConverter}}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=Expander2, Converter={x:Static MyBoolToGridSizeConverter}}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=Expander3, Converter={x:Static MyBoolToGridSizeConverter}}" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Expander Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Expander1">
        <DataGrid />
    </Expander>
    <Expander Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Expander2">
        <DataGrid />
    </Expander>
    <Expander Grid.Row="2" x:Name="Expander3">
        <DataGrid />
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

```
public class BoolToGridSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool && (bool)value)
            return new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);

        return GridLength.Auto;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // this is not needed
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the better idea, rather than using a `StackPanel`. However, I guess the `ScrollViewers` of the `DataGrid`s won't show up then, as the grids have unlimited height?

Comment: Thanks for your answer  @Rachel! I evalueate this in the evening time (in few hours). If @Herdo 's concern is justified, please iterate your answer if you have time.

Comment: @Herdo I forget if Expanders limit the size of their children or not, but you could easily bind the Height of the DataGrid to the Height of the Expander if that were a problem. Or you could try wrapping them in a panel that does limit height, like a `Grid`. You could also wrap them in a `ScrollViewer`, but that would disable the DataGrid's virtualization so I wouldn't recommend that unless you knew in advance your Grid wouldn't have a lot of data.

Comment: @Rachel : This works! Also scrollbars are visible. So when I read my question, I would say the answer is perfect and I will accept it. However when datagrid that's extender is opened when datagrid is empty the extender takes the full area. Could the height be bound somehow also to height of DataGrid?

Comment: @matti You'd have to switch to a `MultiValueConverter` to pass multiple values to the converter, and bind the Item Count for each DataGrid as well. Then if either `Expander.IsExpanded = false` or `ItemCount = 0`, use `GridSize.Auto`

Comment: thanks a lot! actually I found out this class just now from the net. didn't know this can be done. awesome!